# How to resolve connection - obsolete connection settings

Tags: apache, ssl, ssl-certificate

After installing a signed certificate on Apache version 2.4.33, I've noticed the information below under the security tab of my browser's console;

> Connection - obsolete connection settings
>   The connection to this site uses TLS 1.2 (a strong protocol), RSA (an obsolete key exchange), and AES_256_GCM (a strong cipher).

Below is the screenshot of the error above;

[image: Connection - obsolete connection settings][1]

The snippet below reflects my virtual host configuration;

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot "/my/path/to/www"
    ServerName mydomain.com
    ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /my/path/to/mydomainname.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /my/path/to/mydomainname.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /my/path/to/CA.crt
    ErrorLog "/my/path/to/mydomain-error.log"
    CustomLog "/my/path/to/mydomain-access.log" common
    </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: As far as I can see, you did nothing wrong. That looks a lot like Chrome security shaming. That said, here is one of the many articles on security stackexchange : https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/83831/google-chrome-your-connection-to-website-is-encrypted-with-obsolete-cryptograph

Comment: You can use an online scanner such as https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ to have better explanations and examples on what to do.

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!DSS
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
SSLCompression off
SSLSessionTickets off
```

to your virtual host after `SSLEngine on`

Comment: You can go to https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ to generate the needed configuration based on some easy questions.